# How to add exception to python function?

Tags: python, mysql-python, mysql-error-1064

Good day. I wrote an application on python that collects call logs from the Avaya PBX and writes them to the mysql database. It works well, but sometimes the PBX sends an empty string for some reason and the program fails. I attach the screen and code below. I understand that you need to wrap the function in an exception: try except, but I don’t understand how to do it. Please tell me how to do this.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oQPEq.gif)

```
def write_db(item, *agrs):
    connection = pymysql.connect(host='localhost',
                                 user='acdr',
                                 password='it8ejokd',
                                 db='avaya_cdr',
                                 charset='utf8mb4',
                                 cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
    DBTBL = "cdr102019"
    DBFLD = "Date_call, Time_call, `Sec_dur`, `clg_num_in_tag`, `dialed_num`, dep_called, dep_dialed"

    dep_num_call = find_dep(item[3].replace(' ', ''))
    name_dep_call = name_dep(dep_num_call)
    dep_num_dial = find_dep(item[4].replace(' ', ''))
    name_dep_dial = name_dep(dep_num_dial)

    item.append(name_dep_call)
    item.append(name_dep_dial)
    item[1] = item[1] + "00"

    try:
        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            sql = "INSERT INTO "+DBTBL+" ("+DBFLD+") VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)"
            cursor.execute(sql, (item))
        connection.commit()
    finally:
        connection.close()

# Задаем адрес сервера
SERVER_ADDRESS = ('', 5100)

# Настраиваем сокет
server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_socket.bind(SERVER_ADDRESS)
server_socket.listen(5)
print('server is running, please, press ctrl+c to stop')

# Слушаем запросы и пишем в db
while True:
    connection, address = server_socket.accept()

    data = connection.recv(1024)
    if not(b'\x00\x00\x00' in data) and not(b'1370' in data):
        str = data.decode("utf-8")
        item=[str[0:6],str[7:11],str[12:17],str[18:33],str[34:57]]
        print(item)
        write_db(item)

    connection.close()
```

Comment: Could you be more specific about which line of code fails, and with what error? You could wrap the whole function in a generic try/except block, but it's more efficient to try a single line of code, or a few lines, looking for a specific exception.

Comment: Swears at the line:
"write_db (item)"
produces the following error:
'pymysql.err.InternalError: (1292, "Incorrect date value:` `for column' Date_call 'at row 1")'

Comment: It would be helpful to see the full stack trace, since the error is occurring somewhere inside of `write_db(item)`.

Comment: This is a photo of a complete error trace. On my Yandex drive    https://yadi.sk/i/R-zcQ_bXLx5DIQ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to catch the exception, so we can cater for a few types, but just to be sure and get you up and running, you could do the following :)

```
try:
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        sql = (
                "INSERT INTO "+DBTBL+" ("+DBFLD+") VALUES " 
                "(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)"
        )
        cursor.execute(
            sql,
            (item),
        )

    connection.commit()

except Exception as e:
    print("Error occurred: %s"% e)

finally:
    connection.close()
```

Comment: I used " import pymysql.cursors ", how to tune this library? thank)

Comment: Thank you all more. Thanks to you, I completely understood how to work with exceptions) Thank you for being)

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick. I've used all four elements of try/except/else/finally here, with brief explanations of when they're executed.

```py
try:
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        sql = "INSERT INTO "+DBTBL+" ("+DBFLD+") VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)"
        cursor.execute(sql, (item))
except Exception: # If this code fails, ignore it
    pass
else: # If the code inside 'try' succeeds, execute this code. 
    connection.commit()
finally: # Regardless of whether or not the code inside 'try' succeeds, execute this code
    connection.close()
```

Comment: Thank you all more. Thanks to you, I completely understood how to work with exceptions) Thank you for being)